# Matlab datatips: no text visible with view([0 90])

Tags: matlab, plot

When I create a surface plot and use `view([0 90])`, so that I get a nice top-down view of the plot, the datatips are empty, i.e. the text is not visible. See the attached picture. As soon as I move the view a little bit they become visible though. Why is this happening and is there any fix?(1)

I don't really like the workaround to use `view([0 90.0001])` instead. I'd rather see a fix than a workaround.

[image: Matlab invisible datatip]

Mind that this doesn't happen when you save the file as a picture.

(1) It has probably something to do with heights. I think that the text height is at the exact same height as the box, which makes it possible that the text is drawn before the box, overwriting the text. I noticed that the box in that view sometimes disappears behind a surface which has a positive z-axis value.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem (Matlab 2013b). Are you inserting the datatips manually or by code? It seems like a bug, a workaround could be to use your custom datatips: [Tutorial](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2011/10/19/tutorial-how-to-make-a-custom-data-tip-in-matlab/)

Comment: I'm working with Matlab 2013a and I insert them manually. Thanks, I'll have a look.

Comment: Please include the full code to reproduce your problem.